# PHP cURL Location Change

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to display the contents of a page behind a login system. I am able to successfully login and display the first page behind the login system, but any subsequent pages are unable to be displayed.

My understanding of the problem is that cURL follows the headers that are provided after logging in. So, if the order is login.php -> home.php, and I want to go to account.php, I would need another header pointing to that page.

Is that correct? Can I use cURL to display the contents of other pages after logging in?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to save and transmit cookies. This can be done in PHP cURL like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set your regular options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somedomain.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('user'=>'foo', 'pass'=>'bar'));

// set where cookies are saved
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');

// set where cookies are retrieved from when sent to the server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');

// execute login
curl_exec($ch);

// do another request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somedomain.com/restricted_page.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: After that, how do I go about changing the location of the page after using cURL to log in?

Comment: @John: Well this has to be set for each cURL request. Once you log in, request another page by (again) specifying those two options and you should be good.

Comment: I am not sure how to request another page after logging in. Do you have a code example of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @John Smith Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem. Also read the FAQ when you get the time.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am now able to get the next page, but what about getting a page after that? Or navigating to other pages in general?

Comment: @John Smith: Just repeat the last three lines and change the target URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle cookies. They're needed for the session authentication.

Get the Cookie header from the first call and send it with all subsequent calls.

Comment: Could you provide some code demonstrating how I would use cURL after logging in to go to a different page?

Answer (score 0):

You must know how login pages (usually) work. When you log into a site the site will send you a session cookie that you will send again to the website everytime you request a new page. So if you want to emulate the login you must store cookies returned by the login and then include them in every other request to the site.